# Count users by create_timestamp and last login date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to perform a year by year count of users based upon their create_timestamp and their last_login date.

```
USER create_timestamp Last_login
10    2009-06-18       20161029
11    2010-07-01       20110101
12    2011-10-01       20150101
13    2012-12-01       20161101

Year  Count
2009   1
2010   2
2011   3
2012   3
2013   3
2014   3
2015   3
2016   2
```

Would I be looking at using sum and case statements?

Comment: Did you have any query that you tried already that we could finetune?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the xref table like below,create it as permanent table(i have used here temp table) and then join with your table like below

```
create table #xref(yearofemp int)
insert into #xref values(2009)
insert into #xref values(2010)
insert into #xref values(2011)
insert into #xref values(2012)
insert into #xref values(2013)
insert into #xref values(2014)
insert into #xref values(2015)
insert into #xref values(2016)

create table #emp(userid int,create_timestamp datetime,Last_login datetime)
insert into #emp values(10,'2009-06-18','20161029') 
insert into #emp values(11,'2010-07-01','20110101')
insert into #emp values(12,'2011-10-01','20150101') 
insert into #emp values(13,'2012-12-01','20161101') 


select
    a.yearofemp as Year_No
    ,COUNT(a.userid) as Count_of_emp
from
(
select 
    #emp.userid
    ,#xref.yearofemp
from #emp
inner join #xref
on yearofemp  between year(#emp.create_timestamp ) 
and year(#emp.Last_login)
)a
group by a.yearofemp
order by a.yearofemp
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you have index on create_timestamp and Last_login, then this query is able to use it.

```
create table #years(years datetime not null)
insert into #years 
    values
        ('2009-01-01'),
        ('2010-01-01'),
        ('2011-01-01'),
        ('2012-01-01'),
        ('2013-01-01'),
        ('2014-01-01'),
        ('2015-01-01'),
        ('2016-01-01')

create table #data(
    userid int,
    create_timestamp datetime,
    Last_login datetime
)

insert into #data 
    values
        (10,'2009-06-18','20161029'),
        (11,'2010-07-01','20110101'),
        (12,'2011-10-01','20150101'),
        (13,'2012-12-01','20161101'),



select
    year(y.years) as [Year],
    ca.[Count]
from #years y
outer apply (
    select
        count(*) as [Count]
    from #data d
    where y.years between d.create_timestamp and d.Last_login
) ca
```